# how to change the clock widget to 24 hour time from command line

Tags: time, widget, config, clock, gnome

we need the default Gnome clock widget to show the time in the 24 hour format, but need to do it entirely from the command line (via script, no GUI).

anyone know how to do this?  is there a config file somewhere?

thanks

edit: should say that this is for rhel5

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a RHEL5 or even GNOME 2 system available to test this on, but this (or something similar) should work:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/clock_applet/prefs/format 24-hour
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work.  the applet is located in /etc/skel/.gconf/apps/panel/applets/clock/, and oddly enough, gconftool-2 wouldn't take anything with a '.' in the filepath, so i created a symbolic link to that directory in /var/tmp, and then ran gconftool-2 -s -t string /var/tmp/mylink/prefs/format 24-hour.  i saw it updated the gconf xml file, but it still didn't work, even after a logout and then a reboot.

Comment: gconftool-2 doesn't take file paths. That path is a path within the GConf configuration database. Did you try it without /var/tmp?

Comment: this still didn't work.  i issued the command, and it never gave any error or anything.  but upon logout and logging back in, nothing changed.

Comment: I suggest browsing around the configuration database using `gconf-editor` to find the correct key to use with `gconftool-2`. I'd do it myself since I know what I'm looking for, but I don't have a system available, sorry. But this is definitely the way to go.